# Get the specific data input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i have the next form

```
<form>
<input name="name" type="text" value="" />
<input type="submit" id="sub" value="Save" />
</form>
```

and i submit the form on with the next ajax jquery code

```
$(function() {
    $(".form").each(function() {
       $(this).validate({
            submitHandler: function(o) {
                $.post("update.php", $(o).serialize(), function() {
    console.log(this.data)
                })
            }
        })
    })
});
```

the function works fine but i need obtain a one specific value from the console log.

example, on this moment the console log show me this result after submit:

```
name=hi world&sub=save
```

but i want the console log show me the result only the input name value:

```
hi world
```

Answer (score 0):

Just get the value:

```
var value = $(o).find('[name="name"]').val();
console.log(value);
```